# Files or folders in non-standard locations in android project using Android Maven Plugin 4+

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

When I try compile a android project generated with this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-quickstart \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.11 \
  -DgroupId=com.kleber \
  -DartifactId=app2
```

which generates a project with this structure:

```
app2
 -assets
 -res
  ...
  -layout
  -menu
  -values
  ...
 -src
  -main
   -java
    -com
     -kleber
      HelloAndroidActivity.java
 AndroidManifest.xml
 default.properties
 pom.xml
```

I got this error:

```
[ERROR] Found files or folders in non-standard locations in the project!
[ERROR] ....This might be a side-effect of a migration to Android Maven Plugin 4+.
[ERROR] ....Please observe the warnings for specific files and folders above.
[ERROR] ....Ideally you should restructure your project.
[ERROR] ....Alternatively add explicit configuration overrides for files or folders.
[ERROR] ....Finally you could set failOnNonStandardStructure to false, potentially resulting in other failures.
```

I have this `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.kleber</groupId>
    <artifactId>app2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>app2</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <platform.version>4.1.1.4</platform.version>
        <android.plugin.version>4.1.1</android.plugin.version>
        <android.sdk.path>C:\Users\00940831503\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk</android.sdk.path>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!--<groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>-->
                    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <sdk>
                            <platform>29</platform>
                        </sdk>
                    </configuration>
              </plugin>
            <!--<plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>29</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What the correct project structure to compile the project without errors? Is there a maven archetype which generate the project with the correct structure already?

Answer (score 0):

The Android Maven plugin expects `AndroidManifest.xml` in `src/main` rather than in the root.

Option 1: Move `AndroidManifest.xml` to the location in which the plugin expects it, though this may have side effects in the IDE you’re using (Eclipse seems to fine with it, as far as I can tell).

Option 2: Tell the plugin where to look for the file by adding the following to the POM, at `projects/build/plugins/plugin/configuration`:

```
<androidManifestFile>
    ${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml
</androidManifestFile>
```

The same applies to resources if your project has them anywhere other than `src/main/res` (old projects originally built for the Eclipse/ant toolchain have them under `res`). The property for these is `resourceDirectory`.